set Non-Personalized ads in Admob without UMP
I have a simple question.
I saw the code to provide non-personalized ads.
Bundle extras = new Bundle();
extras.putString("npa", "1");

AdRequest request = new AdRequest.Builder()
    .addNetworkExtrasBundle(AdMobAdapter.class, extras)
    .build();

Does it work without UMP? I don't publish my app in EU, so I don't have to use it.
Please help me. thanks.
I tried that code in sample project, but AdMob SDK does not have a function to indicate whether an ad is personalized or not.

If you show non-personalized ads then, I think, there is no need to gather GDPR (or other) consent. Maybe the drawback can be that you will have a drop in displaying ads
